# Using EXISTS with three arguments within a CUBESET function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, mdx

Here is my formula which currently returns `#N/A`:

```
=CUBESET("MyConnection","EXISTS([Customers].[Customer Names].MEMBERS,[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].&[201312],""CustomerMeasureGroup"")")
```

If I change it to the following it functions ok but the third argument of EXISTS is required to get the correct number of items in the set:

```
=CUBESET("MyConnection","EXISTS([Customers].[Customer Names].MEMBERS,[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].&[201312])")
```

Comment: two up-votes but no comments or answers! ...is this a bug?

Comment: Probably people who are seeing these functions for the first time and want to upvote 'rare' questions, but that's just my feeling. It's the first time I see those, for my part.

Comment: @Jerry Do you use excel pivots to connect to `OLAP` cubes at all? Do you know any `MDX`? ....if you do then maybe you could test the above? - is this a bug?

Comment: Sorry, I do use pivot tables but have yet to do external connections, sorry about that. :(

Comment: Maybe you could try single single quotes instead of doubled double quotes for the third argument?

Comment: @FrankPl hi Frank - hope you are well. Not tried yet but will do - Are single quotes legal for that argument of `EXISTS`? Was thinking I could maybe use `NONEMPTY` instead?

Comment: @FrankPl ....as always you're spot on: add it as an answer and I'll mark correct.

Comment: @whytheq Actually, I was not absolutely sure myself if single quotes were legal in that position, I just had the feeling it would be worth a try, as it would be easy to check. hence I did not put that suggestion into an answer directly. I will do so now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to put the measure group name with single single quotes instead of doubled double quotes.

It is not documented clearly somewhere - as far as I know - but in some contexts MDX accepts single or double quotes to mark a string.